# Should I worry about my electrician not being vat registered?

Tags: uk

Is that automatically a Red Flag?

I'm about to ask what credentials he holds and who he's registered with NICEIC, etc.

Assuming those things are OK, is the VAT registration important? (I'm getting domestic work done, and we're in London)

Comment: What exactly does VAT stand for? Thank-you.

Comment: Value Added Tax, it's the UK sales tax (hence the "UK" tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not at all.

If he is a sole trader it is quite possible that he doesn't turn over enough money to need to register for VAT.  Registration is only mandatory above a certain threshold (which changes every year) and is optional below that.  Most traders who don't have to register won't bother as it saves a lot of tax form-filling hassle.

As long as he has the appropriate qualifications, go with it.

He won't have to charge you VAT so you should get the work done cheaper.

Comment: Current (2016) threshold is £82,000 turnover.